# ¿Cómo alinear un subtitulo en plot de R?

Tags: r

tengo el siguiente vector.

```
a<-sample(1:20, 300, T)
```

Y deseo graficarlo en un gráfico de barras.

```
barplot(table(a), sub = "quiero el subtítulo a la izquierda")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo hago para alinear mi subtitulo en la parte izquierda de la gráfica?

He intentado con `pos` y `adj`

Pero no he tenido resultados.

**Muchas Gracias de antemano**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debiera funcionar:

```
barplot(table(a), adj=0, sub = "quiero el subtítulo a la izquierda")
```

Y sino, puedes probar general el título con un `mtext()`:

```
barplot(table(a))
mtext(side=1, line=3,  adj=0, "quiero el subtítulo a la izquierda")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, estimado Patricio.